# Creating new variables using for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create variable names using for loop in python,

I tried the code below:

```
for i in range(5):
    var+str(i)=i
    print(var+str)
```

but it returns a error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

Can Anyone help me this that where i go wrong or there is any other method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a python dictionary.

```
d = {}
for x in range(1, 3):
    d["string{0}".format(x)] = "Foo"

>>> d["string5"]
'Foo'
>>> d
{'string1': 'Hello',
 'string2': 'Hello',
 'string3': 'Hello',
}
```